# Passing new lines in JavaScript function

Tags: php, html, string, escaping

I have a JavaScript function that populates and shows a div when a user hovers over something. I've found out that if the input that I pass to the function contains a blank line, it won't work. Is there an easy way to encode my variables in PHP so it can pass safely?

Javascript:

```
function showPlay(id, info)
{
    var playID = "my_play_div" + id;
    var snippetID = "post_snippet" + id;

    document.getElementById(playID).style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById(snippetID).innerHTML = info;
}
```

I've tried using `$info = htmlentities($info);` on my content and `$info = mysql_real_escape_string($info);` but neither of these got rid of the blank lines, just the quotes (which I need to get rid of as well).

Anyone have a better solution?

Comment: presumably your string contains a newline character - you need to find it and replace it with nothing. Do you know how to do a search and replace in php? Since this is not a "bad" character, the things you have tried so far won't get rid of it...

Comment: How is the PHP variable `$info` getting into the Javascript variable `info`?

Comment: I echo it to get it into the Javascript variable.

You can view my jsfiddle and see that only the Fall Out Boy post works (because this doesn't contain any new lines or anything, I think)

http://jsfiddle.net/Wg9fQ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), `echo json_encode($info);`

Comment: This along with some `htmlentities()` calls seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The php `trim` function will do what you need: see http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php